# Phpmyadmin showing warning "in ./libraries/classes/Template.php#90"

Tags: phpmyadmin

I tried installing the newest version of XAMPP today and after I went to PhpMyAdmin warning showed up.I'm on Mac OS X 13.5.2, Is this going to be a problem in the future?

Here is the Warning:

> Warning in ./libraries/classes/Template.php#90
> Trying to access array offset on value of type null
> Back trace
> Template.php#62: PhpMyAdmin\Template::getTwigEnvironment(string '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig')
> Core.php#140: PhpMyAdmin\Template->__construct()
> Config.php#682: PhpMyAdmin\Core::fatalError(string 'Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!')
> Common.php#169: PhpMyAdmin\Config->checkPermissions()
> index.php#40: PhpMyAdmin\Common::run()